# How to read from CSV file with specific parameters and search for them in external file with a lot of JSONs - java

Tags: java

I am testing a rest API and I want to build a simple java program to do the following (I am new to java). I export in a file multiple JSON responses from JMeter and then I want them to be checked for all the mandatory response parameters. I want the program to read the paramters from a CSV file and to check for each of them everywhere in the JSONs (they are more than 600). Currently I am using this snippet but it just compares what are the differences between the two files:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public Test(){
        System.out.println("Test.Test()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br1 = null;
        BufferedReader br2 = null;
        String sCurrentLine;
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\text1.txt"));
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\text2.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            list1.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
        while ((sCurrentLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
            list2.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
        List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
        tmpList.removeAll(list2);
        System.out.println("content from SavedResponses.txt which is not there in DBResponses.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<tmpList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(tmpList.get(i)); //content from test.txt which is not there in test2.txt
        }

        System.out.println("content from DBResponses.txt which is not there in SavedResponses.txt");

        tmpList = list2;
        tmpList.removeAll(list1);
        for(int i=0;i<tmpList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(tmpList.get(i)); //content from test2.txt which is not there in test.txt
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!